# How to add Google Contact using Nodejs API or curl request

Tags: node.js, api, curl, google-contacts-api

I want to add new contact details if it does not exist in my google contacts

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Nodejs is supported in Google Contacts API. Use [this guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#top_of_page) of google contacts.

> This document is intended for programmers who want to write client
>   applications that can interact with Google's contact lists. It
>   provides a series of examples of basic API interactions. These
>   examples come in various forms, including raw `XML/HTTP requests`,
>   `Java`, `.NET` and `Python` source code.

Also, you can run the sample codes using these protocols.

> If you're using a UNIX system and you want to try the examples in this
>   document without writing any code, you may find the UNIX command-line
>   utilities [**`curl`**](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [**`wget`**](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) useful; for more
>   information, see the manual pages for those utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-contacts-crud npm to read and add google contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Google's official API for NodeJS doesn't use Contacts API, only the People API.

You can connect with Contacts API using the [official googleapis library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#supported-apis) if you're already using it for other purposes by sending a request to the Contacts API after creating the auth client.

Given that you already have the access token of the user (e.g. if you generated it using [Passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport), here's the code:

```
const {google} = require("googleapis");
const authObj = new google.auth.OAuth2({
    access_type: 'offline',
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
});
```

Refresh access token automatically before it expires

```
authObj.on('tokens', (tokens) => {
    const access_token = tokens.access_token
    if (tokens.refresh_token){
        this.myTokens.refreshToken = tokens.refresh_token
        // save refresh token in the database if it exists
    }
        this.myTokens.accessToken = tokens.access_token       
        // save new access token (tokens.access_token)
}
authObj.setCredentials({
    access_token:this.myTokens.accessToken,
    refresh_token:this.myTokens.refreshToken,
});
```

Make the request to Contacts API:

```
authObj.request({
    headers:{
        "GData-Version":3.0
    },
    params:{
        "alt":"json",
        //"q":"OPTIONAL SEARCH QUERY",
        //"startindex":0
        "orderby":"lastmodified",
        "sortorder":"descending",
    },
    url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"
}).then( response => {
    console.log(response); // extracted contacts
});
```